# Xforwarding works on one server, not another

Tags: ssh, x-windows

I'm running ssh -X from my home computer to log into two RedHat servers at work, call them G and B (for Good and Bad).  With G, everything works fine, and I can launch a gui program there and have it show up on my home computer (which btw is running Windows Subsystem for Linux).  But with B, logging in with ssh -X gives the error msg "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0", and I can't launch guis from B.

I've read everything I can find on StackExchange about similar problems (e.g. 
[X11 Forwarding Failure only on a Single Server](https://superuser.com/questions/803585/x11-forwarding-failure-only-on-a-single-server/805060#805060)), and tried (almost?) everything, with no luck.

Afaict, G and B are identical for all the things that should matter: the contents of my ~/.ssh/ files are identical, as are the /etc/ssh/ssh_config, /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and so forth, as well as their permissions; and `xauth list` gives the same output on both, apart from the server name.  I guess they're running slightly different versions of RH, but pretty close.  And they're behind the same firewall.

I created the ~/.Xauthority files on both using

```
xauth add localhost:10.0 . <hexkey>
```

I used identical hexkeys for both, because it was easier to copy one than to create one from scratch.  There's no special meaning to these hexkeys, is there?  They're just random 32 hex digit sequences?  (I also tried creating the .Xauthority files using `xauth generate...`, but that doesn't appear to be possible unless $DISPLAY is defined, and it isn't when I'm just using ssh.  I guess it would be if `ssh -X...` worked, but that's Catch-22.)  And I tried the `xauth extract... xauth merge` trick mentioned in the xauth man page, but that didn't work either; I still get the same error msg.

When I use the -v (verbose) arg with ssh -X, both print out (among other stuff)

```
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
```

as they should.

I tried writing some debugging code in ~/.ssh/rc, based on the code in the the man page for sshd (based on a suggestion in another Q/A here at Stack Exchange).  The code looks like this:

```
echo d="$DISPLAY" > /dev/stderr
read proto cookie
echo p=$proto > /dev/stderr
echo c=$cookie > /dev/stderr
```

This of course prevents XForwarding from working correctly, but the point is to see what's happening.  Here's what this prints out on G:

```
d=localhost:10.0
p=MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
c= <32 hex digits here>
```

And here's what it prints out on B:

```
d=
p=
c=
```

So it appears B is seeing none of the $DISPLAY, proto or cookie, while G sees them just fine.

All along, I've been assuming that the fault was with code or config on B; but now I'm wondering if the fault is on my client (my home computer), and it's sending the needed information to G, but not to B.  But I don't see anything on my home computer that is different between G and B.

What else should I try?